# Using VBA with excel 2007 to compare a number stored in a string to a cell which contains a number formatted as text

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am trying to compare a string (which could be either a combination of numbers and letters, or just numbers) to a cell that is formatted as text (whose contents could be either a combination of numbers and letters, or just numbers). I am finding that when it is comparing a string with both letters and numbers to the cell with matching contents it is able to correctly identify them as the same. However, when the string contains only numbers is compared to the cell containing identical contents it doesn't recognize it as a match. My code:

`If location.Value = identifier then msgbox "Matching"`

Where `identifier` is a string and the cell at `location` is formatted as text.

I have also found that if I instead use:

```
Dim ID_holder As String
ID_holder = location.value
If ID_holder = identifier then msgbox "Matching"
```

that it is then able to recognize when two numbers (stored as strings) are equivalent. Is there anyway to avoid using the extra step of using a string to hold `location.value`? And if anyone knew why my original method was failing that would be much appreciated as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will ensure that whatever the value in `location` is, gets compared as a string.

```
Dim ID_holder As String
ID_holder = cstr(location.value)
If ID_holder = cstr(identifier) then msgbox "Matching"
```

Comment: Good call, that worked well. I decided to go with `If CStr(location.Value) = identifier then msgbox "Matching"` just to eliminate the extra string variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `If CStr(location.Value) = CStr(identifier) then msgbox "Matching"` - that way you're always comparing a string to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use FormulaR1C1 instead of Value to compare.

```
Sub Macro1()
Set a = Range("A1")
Set b = Range("A2")

If a.FormulaR1C1 = "123" Then MsgBox "a: Match"

If b.FormulaR1C1 = "abc" Then MsgBox "b: Match"

End Sub
```